# For loop pattern

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have an assignment for college,
anyway i need to make this pattern 
OutPut:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Problem_11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                for (string o = "*";); //Nested for loop
                {
                    Console.Write(o);
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Error   1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Error   2   Invalid expression term ')'

Error   3   Invalid expression term '{'

Error   4   ) expected

Error   5   { expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <=i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you HackerMan this is perfect,

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an inner loop, use the [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload that let's you repeat a char

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}\n", new String('*', i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, but for the problem it is required of me to use a for loop

Comment: @user3415389 you are still using a for loop, your just not using 2

Comment: Awesome Answer though james this will come in handy for another issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can *simplify* your solution:

```
...
static void Main(string[] args) {
  // More natural to declare loop variable (int i) in the loop
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) 
    Console.WriteLine(new String('*', i)); // <- No inner loop required

  Console.ReadLine();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will never end once it's compiled as there's no condition, but that's another issue.  One problem is the semi-colon was outside the parenthesis in the nested for loop.

```
for (string o = "*";;)
```

Comment: Thanks martin, now atleast it runs, even though theres a infinite loop, but why is for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) not stopping it?

Comment: Because there's an infinite loop preventing the first loop of the first for() loop from ever completing.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the inner for loop:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
 {
      Console.Write("*");
 }
```